# using pyshark to filter and to choose the first GET packet

Tags: pyshark

I am using pyshark to filter a saved pcap file .
the filter I'm using is:

```
http.request.method == GET && !ip.ttl==180 && ip.src==100.100.19.42
```

(at the end there is a link to a screenshot of the pcap file after using this filter.)
my question is, how can I get to and print the HTTP layer contents of the GET packet(found in second row as shown in screenshot)
using python code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctRYN.jpg)
Is there a way to search for the first GET packet and find it?

Comment: Anyone?? I really need help in this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use scapy instead.

```
from scapy.all import *
packets = rdpcap('your_capture.pcap')
for packet in packets:
    if packet['IP'].ttl != 180 and packet['IP'].src == '100.100.19.42':
        try:
            if 'GET' in packet['Raw'].load:
                print 'GET:',packet['Raw'].load
                return packet
        except:
            pass
```